# Outlook Add-In Application.ItemSend not Running

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on an add-in that runs when an email is sent. If the message contains specific text, it cancels sending the message and moves it into drafts. This works when sending emails directly from Outlook, but it doesn't run when the email is generated by another program and sent through Outlook. In this case, the email goes to the Outbox for a couple seconds and then sends like normal.

```
Private Sub OnItemSend(Item As System.Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) _
                   Handles Application.ItemSend


    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Item, Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim mydrafts As Outlook.Folder
    myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    mydrafts = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts)
    myDestFolder = mydrafts
    If InStr(mail.Body, "Message") = 1 Then

        Cancel = True
        mail.Move(myDestFolder)



    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the other program? If the message is sent using Extended MAPI, `Application.ItemSend` will not fire.

Comment: The other program is bidding software we just go. I am not sure how it sends the email other than that it goes through Outlook.

Comment: Do you see that event fire in OutlookSpy (click Application, go to the Events tab, look at the log at the bottom of the window)?

Comment: The only event that fired was when I received the email (I sent it to myself). Nothing happened when it sent.

Comment: Then there isn't anything you can do if you want to cancel the message submission.

Comment: Is there a way to have it run when an item is added to the Outbox folder as opposed to the ItemSend event?

Comment: Sure, Items.ItemAdd on the Sent Items folder should still fire, but it will fire after the message is sent, so you won't be able to modify the outgoing message or cancel the submission.